# Porting a VSCode theme to Emacs?

Tags: themes

Does anyone know of an easy way to port a VSCode theme to emacs? I found a [Python program](https://gitlab.com/valtrok/doom-theme-generator) that converts a json file created from [terminal.sexy](https://terminal.sexy/) into a doom-theme, but have not been able to find an easy way to export the VSCode color theme to terminal.sexy. It's straightforward enough to [get the color theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970372/how-to-get-the-colors-of-the-current-theme-in-vs-code) hex codes from VSCode, but it's unclear which colors from VSCode should correspond to which colors on terminal.sexy. Aside from playing with this sort of thing manually until it looks right, does anyone have any advice on how to proceed, or does anyone have any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Themeforge: https://nice.github.io/themeforge/

It generates Emacs and Vim theme from VS Code theme's JSON.

Source code: https://github.com/nice/themeforge

I'm the author of this online tool.

Comment: This is, so far, a link-only answer. So it risks being deleted. Please summarize, in your answer, what your tool does which answers the question. Thx.